# best ux for users to input multiple strings

Tags: website-design, input, input-fields, inline-edit

I have a web form where in users may input a list of names similar to:

```
Mike, Joe, Ann, Sam
```

The UI should allow for simple edits. This data will be saved and displayed on another page for informational/ read only purpose as well as on the form that takes the inputs and another form that allows for editing the input. currently the enter/ edit functionality is part an parcel of the same UI since entering should allow for editing ... and editing allows for complete deletion and re-entering of strings.

currently I am using a plain text box but it seems like a less than elegant solution, especially with jquery able to do great things on web.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @kacalapy. Please clarify your constraints. What is the maximum number of names someone would need to add? What is the median number? Is there an existing list of names that people must select from? How frequent is the need to edit vs the need to add? When editing, are people concerned with the full list or with an individual name?

Comment: How about something similar to the field where you entered tags for this question ?

Answer (score 2):

The best I've seen is the input you selected (type in entries with commas) which then turns into tags, a la gmail. That way every comma entered creates a tag, and in theory removing the comma brings back the text (though that's technically more complicated). It provides a really simple UX with no real training, except that people are currently used to the gmail way of doing it, where you delete the tag entirely instead of "editing" it.

Comment: +1 - The tagging right here on UXSE works in a similar way. This answer would be even better if it was supported by a screen shot that communicated the interaction ; )